# How to set main file in latextools with Sublime Text 3 editor

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

The point is simple, how to set the "master file" that always will be compiled in Sublime Text 3 editor using standard `Ctrl-b` command (it could using sublime's projects).

Additional feature I'm looking for is setting compilation directory. Where it should be specified?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm the developer of LaTeXTools. To set the master file, you need to add the following line at the very top (i.e. as the first line) of any included files:

`%!TEX root = yourmasterfile.tex`

The README has further details.

Right now there is no support for setting a compilation directory other than the one where the master file resides. It's something a few users have requested, so I may get to it eventually, but it will require some pretty extensive changes (I think).

Update: If you're using a .sublime-project file, you can add the master file under the settings property. See the official [README](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/README.markdown#multi-file-documents).

```
{
  "settings": {
      "TEXroot": "yourfilename.tex"
  }
}
```

In my case I had to provide the absolute path for the `TEXroot` file.

Comment: Kudos for creating LatexTools - really awesome work, and I use your stuff all the time. I have a `my_thesis.tex` file with `include` directives to `main/xyz.tex` files. I've tried putting both `%!TEX root = my_thesis.tex` and `../my_thesis.tex`. At first it didn't work, but when I put the `bibliography` command directly into `my_thesis.tex` it started working great.

Comment: I should add that I only noticed this on Windows with MikTex. On linux and osx, the `bibliography` command did not have to be in the main `my_thesis.tex` file.

Comment: I just realized how many hours I could have saved if I had known that when starting my thesis. Thank you!!! It also jumps right to the edited part in the pdf when you build it.

Comment: The Latextools documentation says to use the key "latextools.tex_root" instead of "TEXroot" as in comment above. The latter works and the former doesnt for me. Any ideas whats going on there?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the developer has archived the LaTextools. Following oweydd, I met the same condition using ST 4. The solution is to replace "latextools.tex_root" with "TEXroot". Anyway, much appreciate the developer's contribution.